# Visual Studio 2015 Mac Agent not connecting to Macbook

Tags: macos, visual-studio, ssh, xamarin

I am trying to connect Visual Studio to Xamarin Studio on my Mac.
Problem is the Mac Agent Connection is not completing.
It just sticks at, 'Trying to connect'.
Both Xamarin and Visual Studio are updated to latest stable release and I have checked the password from Windows as well as that the connection in allowed on my Mac within sharing settings.
I typed the wrong password once to check that it was reaching the Mac and got a bad password error, so it is trying, just not following through.

Has anybody else had this issue?

EDIT: So there is a connection. I ran `netstat` on my Mac and can see the connection to my desktop. However there is still no activity visible between the applications.

Xamarin Studio 5.10 on the Mac and Xamarin 4.0.1.93.

They are running on separate machines on the same subnet.

```
netstat 
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     
tcp6       0      0  localhost.ssh          localhost.49826        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  richards-mbp.con.ssh   desktop-lksrm6c..63356 ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  richards-mbp.con.ssh   desktop-lksrm6c..63355 ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  richards-mbp.con.ssh   desktop-lksrm6c..63353 ESTABLISHED
```

And using Putty on port 22 from the Windows machine establishes a connection just fine.

```
Using username "richardcurteis".
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Last login: Thu Feb  4 19:51:38 2016 from ::1
 ~  
whoami
richardcurteis
 ~  
ls
Applications            Google Drive            Scripts
Desktop                 Justinmind              WebstormProjects
Development             Library                 eclipse
Documents               Movies                  go-lang-idea-plugin
Downloads               Music                   settings.jar
Dropbox                 Pictures                untitled.py
Dropbox (Old)           Public                  work
 ~  
Using username "richardcurteis".
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Last login: Thu Feb  4 19:51:38 2016 from ::1
 ~  
whoami
richardcurteis
```

[image: With network IP]
[image: With human readable host name]

Comment: you must enable communication between the Xamarin extension for Visual Studio and your Mac via Remote Login.
Check : 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/xamarin-mac-agent/

Comment: Which version of Xamarin do you have installed on your Mac and Windows machine? Also, is your version of Windows on a separate computer or running as a virtual machine?

Comment: `Xamarin Studio 5.10` on the Mac and `Xamarin 4.0.1.93`.
They are running on separate machines on the same network.

I have gone through the steps in the guide exactly as posted by @PuchoEric

Comment: It's worked for you? @RichC

Comment: @PuchoEric No it hasn't, I think what may be the problem is that I do not have the right type of Xamarin account, I was using the free trial. See this question I posted.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211609/does-mac-agent-for-xamarin-require-an-apple-developer-account

Comment: Are both machines listed on your Xamarin account on their site as licensed machines?

Comment: Yeah but as trials. When I get the license later on today I'll post an update

Comment: That´s only a business feature from what I know. The Indie licence won´t work

Comment: I'm running into this exact problem and I've got a business account. Both my mac and my pc are licensed to my account and both are running the same version of Xamarin studio (5.10.2 b56). I've got the firewall turned off on both machines and remote login is enabled for everyone on my mac. I can successfully ssh into my mac from my pc with no issue. I've even tried connecting them directly with a patch cable. The xamarin build host was a little temperamental but XMA seems downright broken.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58357/cant-connect-to-mac-from-vs led me right to the issue. My .bashrc was echoing some text to terminal on every login. Commenting that out fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Problem. It's annoying. I can SSH to the Mac, and with the correct credentials, it says's "can't connect" and with the wrong credentials it says "wrong username / password".

The problem exists since November 2015. They don't fix it. Amusing for a 999$ product.

[Link to xamarin forum thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55970/mac-agent-not-working-cant-connect/p1)