# Does Mac Agent for Xamarin require an Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I am trying to set up Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 to run iOS apps.
The problem I have is that I cannot connect with my Mac using the 'Mac Agent'.

I believe this is necessary in order to develop iOS on Windows. 
I have an open question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208471/visual-studio-2015-mac-agent-not-connecting-to-macbook)) on it from a technical perspective, but I wanted to check to see that I am not going down the wrong path with my troubleshooting without overloading the original post with a separate question.

And have the new question specific enough as to be picked up by other users asking the same.

**Question:** Does the use of Visual Studio (and the Mac agent to connect to OSX) require a full license of Xamarin or an Apple Developer account to work?

I can find nothing wrong technically so I'm wondering if the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need an Apple Developer account.  However, using the Visual Studio integration requires a Xamarin business license.